# RobotFramework Appium running on iOS real device is slow

Tags: appium, robotframework, appium-ios

I'm using Appium version 1.15.1 and testing on real device. I'm facing very slow testing during using Xpath as a locator. Is there any solution to help improve speed? beside use ID instead.

Here is my sample:

```
Set Up And Open iOS Application

    Open Application    http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub     
    ...     platformName=${platformName}   
    ...     platformVersion=${platformVersion}   
    ...     deviceName=${deviceName}   
#   ...     app=${APP_LOCATION}  
    ...     udid=${udid}  
    ...     bundleId=${BUNDLE_ID}  
    ...     automationName=${automationName}
```

Comment: How long does a simple script take (please add that script to your question.) How do you conclude that it is slow. What have you already tried to overcome the slowness.

Comment: its took around 5s or 6s to search xpath

Comment: Could you provide some sample code around the xpath ? I suppose there are a number of factor outside of RF to consider. Device speed, automation machine specs.

Comment: @BrianO'Neill It's just click some element , it's so simple. machine running is iMac 2007 with Ram 8GB , Processor quad Core 3.5 Core i5. Device run test is iPhone 8 Plus. i suppose to get some trick to get it better speed ,because i can't wait developer to add AccesbilityID for me.